# IllegalArgumentException in ImageIO.read

Tags: java, swing, jframe, embedded-resource, javax.imageio

I'm trying to use `ImageIO.read` to load an image as a `BufferedImage`.

Here's the code:

```java
public class Sprite {
    private BufferedImage image;

    public Sprite(String img) {
        URL imageUrl = Sprite.class.getResource(img);
        try {
            BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(imageUrl);
        } catch (IOException e) {}
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Sprite sprite = new Sprite("../images/house.png");
    }
}
```

The directory my code is in looks like this:

```
project
  | -- src
  |       | -- Main.java
  | -- images
  |       | -- house.png
```

And the exact error I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1388)
    at game.Sprite.<init>(Sprite.java:12)
    at game.Main.main(Main.java:5)
```

Changing the input URL from `"../images/house.png"` to `"/../images/house.png"` does not fix nor change this error.

The image is in the same folder as the `.class` files.

If it helps, I'm using IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting a BufferedImage as a resource so it will work in JAR file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17007448/getting-a-bufferedimage-as-a-resource-so-it-will-work-in-jar-file)

Comment: Thank you Aposhian, your solution worked.